# Error Code: 1452. Cannot add or update a child row

Tags: mysql

I am trying to load data to following tables:

```
-- -----------------------------------------------------
-- Table `mydb`.`Gener`
-- -----------------------------------------------------    
CREATE  TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `mydb`.`Gener` (
  `Movie_Name` VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL ,
  `Genres_Type` VARCHAR(100) NULL ,
  `Movie_Year` VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL ,
  PRIMARY KEY (`Movie_Name`, `Movie_Year`) ,
  CONSTRAINT `fk_Gener_Movie1`
    FOREIGN KEY (`Movie_Name` , `Movie_Year` )
    REFERENCES `mydb`.`Movie` (`Name` , `Year` )
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION)

-- -----------------------------------------------------
-- Table `mydb`.`Movie`
-- -----------------------------------------------------    
CREATE  TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `mydb`.`Movie` (
  `Name` VARCHAR(100) NULL ,
  `Lenght` INT(20) NULL ,
  `Year` VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL ,
  `id` INT(5) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT ,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`, `Name`, `Year`) )

-- -----------------------------------------------------
-- Table `mydb`.`tempGener`
-- -----------------------------------------------------    
CREATE TABLE `mydb`.`tempGener' (
    `mGName` VARCHAR(100),
    `mGType` VARCHAR(100),
    `mGYear` VARCHAR(100)
)
```

I successfully uploading data to following two tables.

- `tempGener`,
- `movie`.

Now I trying to load data to my `Gener` table by using following command,

```
INSERT INTO gener (Movie_Name, Genres_Type, Movie_Year)
(SELECT movie.Name, tempgener.mGType , movie.Year
 FROM tempgener, movie)
```

But I receive following errors:

> Error Code: 1452. Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key
>   constraint fails (`mydb3`.`gener`, CONSTRAINT `fk_Gener_Movie1`
>   FOREIGN KEY (`Movie_Name`, `Movie_Year`) REFERENCES `mydb`.`movie`
>   (`Name`, `Year`) ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE NO ACTION)

Comment: Side note: `Movie_Year VARCHAR(100)` is what I call future-proof programming xD

Comment: It looks like you've created a cartesian product in your join: `FROM tempgener, movie` (with no where clause). I doubt this was intentional, as you'll probably get every combination of year and film name. It's much better if you use ANSI style joins: `FROM tempgener INNER JOIN Movie ON [condition]`

Comment: Could you please show a sample of the data you have inserted into the `tempGener` and `movie` tables?

Answer (score 0):

I solve my problem, the problem was, I was missing WHERE statement.
Thanks for every body giving me fast response.